# JavaScript Array mapping

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider the following scenario;

```
var defaultArr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var availArr = [];
var selectedArr = [];
```

If I am passing array some `index`'s value in param's, I need to split up my array's

Example:

If Array Index : `0,2`

Expected result:

```
availArr = ['b', 'd'];
selectedArr = ['a', 'c'];
```

Is there any default method to achieve this?

Comment: use indexof and push into arr

Comment: filter checking for the index once to get `selectedArr`, then filter NOT-ting the previous predicate for `availArr`?

Comment: I can use `indexOf` for populating `selectedArr`. What about `availArr`?

Comment: @Guedes that is more suited for _sequential_ elements, OP wants _alternating_.

Comment: [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is even more insteresting

Comment: there is a great lib sugar.js it has very good array methods https://sugarjs.com/docs/

Comment: @Ranjith - simply do the opposite to populate `availArr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Failrly easy with [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var defaultArr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var indexes = [0,2];

var result = defaultArr.reduce(function(p, c, i){
  if(indexes.indexOf(i)>-1)
    p.selectedArr.push(c);
  else
    p.availArr.push(c);
  return p;
}, {availArr: [], selectedArr:[]});;


console.log('availArr',result.availArr);
console.log('selectedArr',result.selectedArr);
```

This works because `reduce` takes a callback argument which is passed 3 arguments - in my example above

- `p` the seed object passed in
- `c` the current array element
- `i` the index of the current element

And uses that information along with `indexOf` to determine which result array to push to.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`Array#reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) and iterate the indices array.

```js
var defaultArr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    availArr = defaultArr.slice(),
    selectedArr = [],
    indices = [0, 2];

indices.reduceRight(function (_, a) {
    selectedArr.unshift(availArr.splice(a, 1)[0]);
}, 0);

console.log(availArr);
console.log(selectedArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var defaultArr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var availArr = [];
var selectedArr = [];


function splitArray(indexes) {
  availArr = defaultArr; 
  indexes.forEach(function(idx) {
    let item = availArr.splice(idx, 1)[0];
    selectedArr.push(item);
  })
}

splitArray([0, 2]);

console.log(availArr);
console.log(selectedArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Array methods like *forEach* and *includes*

```js
var given = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var indexes = [0, 2];
var available = [];
var selected = [];

given.forEach(function (v, i) {
  if (indexes.includes(i)) {
    selected.push(v);
  } else {
    available.push(v);
  }
});

document.write(JSON.stringify({
  given: given,
  available: available,
  selected: selected
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

In JS `Array.prototype.reduceRight()` is the ideal functor to iterate over an array and to morph it by removing items. Accordingly i would approach this job as follows;

```js
var defaultArr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
       indices = [0, 2];
        result = defaultArr.reduceRight((p,c,i,a) => indices.includes(i) ? p.concat(a.splice(i,1)) : p ,[]);
console.log(defaultArr,result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array.splice` + `array.concat` to achieve this

```js
var defaultArr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var availArr = [];
var selectedArr = [];

function parseIndexes(indexArr){
  var deleteCount = 0;
  availArr = defaultArr.map(x=>x);
  indexArr.forEach(function(i){
    selectedArr = selectedArr.concat(availArr.splice(i-deleteCount,1))
    deleteCount++;
  });   
  console.log(availArr, selectedArr)
}

parseIndexes([0,2])
```

Answer (score 0):

With only [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter)

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var indexes = [0, 2]
array.filter(function(el, i) { 
    return indexes.indexOf(i) !== -1 
});

// ["a", "c"]
```

With `array` the array of your elements, objects, strings... and `indexes` the array containing all the indexes of the elements you want to keep, you just remove from the `array`array all the elements whose id isn't in the`indexes` array.

Answer (score 0):

The array of all selected entries can be obtained in one line via the `Array.map`:

```
var defaultArr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
var index = [0,2]
var selectedArr = index.map(i => defaultArr[i]) //=> ['a', 'c']
```

Then the array of the remaining entries can be retrieved e.g. with [the Ramda's difference operator](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#difference):

```
var availArr = R.difference(defaultArr, selectedArr) //=> ['b', 'd']
```